# How to hide div in html page in app.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, sencha-touch

After login I am showing some user modules on html page. I want to hide it when user not have an access for that module by admin. I am use sencha/ ExtJs for front-end.

I want to hide this component after user login if he don't have permission for it.
here is my code(please see below Image)
[image]

I want to hide this Live Tracking On user login if user don't have access for this.

Design for this is bellow
[image]

I want to Create a function in App.js (In controller).
Can you help me for this...

Comment: can you try to add a style of `display:none` to the div which you don't want to show based on your condition? Better way would be to create a new css selector and add that class to your div dynamically. Does that help?

Comment: Please never submit code as an image.  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are validating the user or when it logs in, whenever that happens add style `display:none`

using javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('live-tracking').style.displ‌​ay= "none"
```

Comment: I didn't getting this.. how to... display:none

Comment: Using javascript: `document.getElementsByClassName('live-tracking').style.display= "none"`

Answer (score 1):

Your controller {

validateAndLogin : function () {

```
var isValidated = // check validation according your requirement. 
if(isValidated) {
  //display your html view and do following after adding id attribute to that         
  //div which you want to hide.
  document.getElementById('livetracking').style.display='none';
}
```

}

Comment: I want to hide <div> by class
like my div is <div class="abc-def">

Comment: Javascript also provide the function to get elements by class name. So you can use 
document.getElementsByClassName('abc-def').style.display='none'
In place of  document.getElementById('livetracking').style.display='none';